# Infalling Observer and Black Hole Information Loss?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I was thinking about the following scenario today, and I was hoping to find a more detailed explanation.

Suppose you have an observer $A$ falling into a black hole and an observer $B$ at infinity. In classical GR, it takes infinitely long for $A$ to even reach the event horizon of the black hole, according to $B$. However, we know also that black holes emit Hawking radiation and therefore evaporate in a *finite* amount of time. Thus, it seems to me that $B$ should see $A$ approaching closer and closer to the event horizon until the black hole evaporates, at which point $A$ continues moving onward.

However, in $A$'s frame, it takes finite proper time for $A$ to reach the event horizon. Thus, $A$ actually enters the black hole, so it also seems like the information contained in $A$ (along with everything else in the black hole) gets emitted as purely thermal Hawking radiation as the black hole is evaporating.

How can we reconcile the above two interpretations? Does this argument demonstrate that unitarity is not violated by Hawking radiation?